# How to stop animation on a 3d model in unity?

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

how can you stop the animation on a 3D model with animation until it has had another object collide with it?

Answer (score 0):

Well you could just use the following code to stop the animation. The code also handles the animation speed.

```
// Walk backwards
animation["Walk"].speed = -1.0;

// Walk at double speed
animation["Walk"].speed = 2;
```

So essentially you could just technically use the following code to stop the animation:

```
animation["Walk"].speed = 0;
```

Here is the script reference for [animation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Animation.html). Also look at the [animation state docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/AnimationState.html).

Then for the colliding part, just use the [OnCollisionEnter](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html) method.

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
    //enable the animation
    animation["Walk"].speed = 1;
}
```